# labour v.s. labourer

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What's the difference between them when I mean "worker"?

In other word, which one below is right?

1. Companies can barely find young labours in an ageing society.
2. Companies can barely find young labourers in an ageing society.

Comment: "labour" as a noun never denotes a person, it refers to the work done by a labourer. #1 is trying to talk about a "labour" being "young" which is nonsensical. #2 is better. On another note, I would avoid the word "barely" in this context.

Comment: You might say "Companies find it increasingly difficult to find young labourers in an ageing society."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labor (labour) denotes work (unskilled). Laborer (labourer) is the individual(s) doing the "labor". The difference between sentence 1 & 2 is that sentence one is incorrect and shows incorrect usage of the word labor (labour).

Comment: Just to be clear: `labor` is the American spelling, `labour` the British spelling. Both derive ultimately from Latin `labor`.

Comment: I am aware. That is why I left them in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, @RebelSoul, but actually that comment was intended for the GP and any future readers who might not be comfortable enough with English dialects to know that; I assumed that you knew.